# SQL Server self join for virtual table

Tags: sql, sql-server, self-join

Can I self join "virtual" table (result of union of some tables)?

```
    SELECT
      [VIRTUAL_TABLE].[Name]  AS [name],
      [VIRTUAL_TABLE].[ID]    AS [id]
    FROM (
       SELECT
        ...
       FROM [...]

       UNION

       SELECT
        ...
       FROM [...]
    ) AS [VIRTUAL_TABLE]
    -- INNER JOIN [VIRTUAL_TABLE] ON ... ???
```

I'm using an SQL Server.

Thanx!

Comment: What do you mean Virtual table?

Comment: Virtual table comes in SQlite and in MS SQL we can use temp table and yes we can use union between temp tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a common table expression (CTE):

```
with virtualTable as(
   SELECT
    ...
   FROM [...]

   UNION

   SELECT
    ...
   FROM [...]
) 
select vt1.field,
       vt2.field
from   virtualTable vt1 join virtualTable vt2 on vt1.someField = vt2.otherField
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to write it classically, you have to duplicate your TSQL code. However, you can use CTE for this.

Maybe that code solve your problem:

```
SELECT VIRTUAL_TABLE_1.*
FROM (SELECT 'James' NAME, '12' ID) AS VIRTUAL_TABLE_1,
     (SELECT 'James' NAME, '12' ID) AS VIRTUAL_TABLE_2
WHERE VIRTUAL_TABLE_1.ID = VIRTUAL_TABLE_2.ID
```